# SOQL query not returning any record even when it is present. Trigger failing due to this

Tags: soql

I have a trigger where I have to Insert a new Record in the "CaseTeamMember" object whenever a new "Case" is created. For this I have to query the "CaseTeamRole = CSO" .

In my developer console when I give the query only as below then I get the CSO record.

**Select Id,Name from CaseTeamRole**

[image]

But when I try to fetch the Id of only the "CSO record then it is not fetching. I have tried queries in multiple ways as below :

1) Select Id,Name from CaseTeamRole where Name LIKE 'CS%' (Before this query used to get the CSO record. Now after sandbox refresh this is also failing)

2) Select Id,Name from CaseTeamRole where Name = 'CSO'

3) Select Id,Name from CaseTeamRole where Name LIKE 'C%'

[image]

If I give any other record then those are getting fetched .

[image]

This is not allowing me to even create a case now due to SOQL not fecthing any record in trigger :(

Please help me in understanding what might be the issue.

**Edit**
Trigger

```
Trigger CaseTrigger on Case (After Insert) 
{
    If(Trigger.isAfter)
    {
        If(Trigger.isInsert)
        {
            For(Case C : Trigger.New)
            {
                IF((C.Record_Type_Name__c == 'Delivery Escalation' || C.Record_Type_Name__c.startsWith('CSP')) && (C.CreatedDate == C.LastModifiedDate))
                {
                    CaseTriggerHelper.CreateNewCaseTeamMember(Trigger.New);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class:

```
Public Class CaseTriggerHelper
{
    Public Static Void CreateNewCaseTeamMember(List<Case> CaseIds)
    {  
        List<CaseTeamMember> CTMList = New List <CaseTeamMember>(); 

        CaseTeamRole CTR = [Select Id,Name from CaseTeamRole where Name LIKE 'CS%'];
        system.debug('---CTR---'+CTR);

        Try
        {
            For(Case C : CaseIds)
            {
                CaseTeamMember CTM = New CaseTeamMember();

                CTM.ParentId = C.Id;
                CTM.MemberId = C.CreatedById;
                CTM.TeamRoleId = CTR.Id;
                CTMList.Add(CTM);
            }
            Insert CTMList;
        }
        Catch(Exception e){
            } 
    }
}
```

> UPDATE

Should I pass a list of cases in my trigger handler in this way?

```
Trigger CaseTrigger on Case (After Insert) { 
  Set<ID> ids = Trigger.newMap.keySet(); 
  If(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert) { 
    For(Case C : Trigger.New) { 
       List<Case> C = [SELECT Id FROM Case 
                          WHERE ((Record_Type_Name__c == 'Delivery Escalation' || 
                                  Record_Type_Name__c.startsWith('CSP')) &&
                                 (CreatedDate == LastModifiedDate))];  
       CaseTriggerHelper.CreateNewCaseTeamMember(C); 
    } 
  } 
 }
```

Thanks!
Ruchi

Comment: did you try OF, BU as filter. Were you able to get records for these?

Comment: Yes I am able to get records for them.

Comment: are you sure that user, that fire trigger, have “Customize Application” AND “Manage Users” permission?

Comment: I am a "System Admin" there and the query Select Id,Name from CaseTeamRole where Name LIKE 'CS%'   was working before the sandbox refresh.

Comment: and those case team role still exists, right? no trailing space etc? just **like** operator stopped working?

Comment: Yes...There are no trailing spaces present. I just want the Id of the "CSO" record which I am unable to get in any way.

Comment: did you create record after SB refersh?

Comment: Can you post the trigger here?

Comment: @Tushar sharma : No I did not create record after refresh...It was already present

Comment: then first try to edit and save this record and again query same record. I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: @TusharSharma : Editing and saving did not help. I am unable to understand what is weird with it. Before it was at least searching with 'CS%' . Now nothing is working.

Comment: i dont see why query wouldn't work other than what @sfdcgod mentioned. I might actually edit the record and delete the name and type in back CSO. I would also try to add a % before CS in my query just to see if there is prepended encoding characters

Comment: your triggerHandler is not designed correctly as you are calling it once per element of `Trigger.new` and then (hence in a for loop), querying `CaseTeamRole`.  You should pass to your trigger handler a list of Cases that meet the criteria and, then, in the handler, query  the CaseTeamRole only once.  An even better design would be to query all CaseTeamRoles into a static map that you use to lookup the roleId

Comment: @crop1645 : Should I pass a list of cases in my trigger handler in this way? 

Trigger CaseTrigger on Case (After Insert) 
{
    Set<ID> ids = Trigger.newMap.keySet();
    If(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert)
    {
        For(Case C : Trigger.New)
        {
        List<Case> C = [SELECT Id FROM Case WHERE ((Record_Type_Name__c == 'Delivery Escalation' || Record_Type_Name__c.startsWith('CSP')) && (CreatedDate == LastModifiedDate))];
                
        CaseTriggerHelper.CreateNewCaseTeamMember(C);
                
        }        
    }
}

Comment: i added your comment into your OP but the answer is no - you are still doing soql inside of for loops - you need to query outside of the for loop to provide the records to the handler

Comment: @Ruchi That is a separate question. You should accept the below answer as it appears to resolve your query issue and ask a *separate question* about your trigger structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I observed the same issue in our full sandbox after a refresh.  I believe it is a bug, though it is not yet on Salesforce's known issues list.

If you change your query to `Select Id,Name from CaseTeamRole where Name != 'CSO'`, your query will probably return all results except the record where the Name is CSO.

If you change your query to `Select Id,Name from CaseTeamRole where Name like '%s%'`, your query will probably return two records: CSO and Global Sales Manager.

It looks to me that the results only return if > 1 row is in the result set.

The workaround that could work for you is to query for all CaseTeamRole records and then loop through each result looking for Name = 'CSO'.  For example:

```
for (CaseTeamRole ctr: [select id, name from CaseTeamRole])
{
 if(ctr.Name == 'CSO')
 {..do stuff.. }
}
```

If you happened to open a case with Salesforce, would be curious to know if they confirmed whether it is a bug or not.

Comment: I did the same thing later to resolve this issue. Did not found any other way. I had not opened any case with salesforce.

Comment: I came across this issue myself recently. On a hunch, I cleared the value of the field and re-entered it and the problem went away. I had experience in the past where someone pasted a value into the name field and quite possibly included a non-breaking space or something similar. Thus causing it to not to match on SOQL filters.  I know it seems farfetched, I wouldn't have belived this solved it if I didn't see it myself. In my opinion, this is a bug.

Answer (score 0):

1. double click on the cso field and copy the value and now search with this value, this will find the results.

this happens sometime because of some hidden different encoding characters.

Comment: I tried your approach but did not help :(